# PHP multi database connect

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
<?
    $db1 = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or dir("can not connect Mysql Server");
    mysql_select_db("1",$db1) or dir("Can not connect to the MySQL Server.");

    $db2 = mysql_connect("localhost","root","root") or dir("can not connect Mysql Server");
    mysql_select_db("2",$db2) or dir("Can not connect to the MySQL Server.");
?>

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db1.tags WHERE db1.catalog='fresh tag' ");
```

If I connect from a multi database, how to make a MySQL query from db1?

Comment: Why don't you do it OO, which makes it possible for you to do $db1->query("SELECT * FROM db1.tags WHERE db1.catalog = 'fresh tag'"); instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Specify it in the query.

```
$result = mysql_query($query, $db1);
```

If the second parameter ($db1) is omitted, it will use the last defined resource ($db2)

Answer (score 2):

Look in the [manual](http://www.php.net/mysql_query).

```
resource mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier ] )
```

Like you already do for `mysql_select_db()`, you can specify the connection as the second parameter.

Answer (score 2):

The second parameter of [mysql_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) is the connection resource. it will query against that connection.

Answer (score 2):

See the [mysql_query](http://php.net/mysql_query) documentation. You just pass in `link_identifier` as the second parameter.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db1.tags WHERE db1.catalog='fresh tag'", $db1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
mysql_query($query, $db1);
```

or

```
mysql_select_db();
```

Answer (score 1):

If they are both in localhost you do not need to connect 2 times. you could simply do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM db2.tags WHERE id IN(SELECT id FROM db1.tags WHERE id=1)
```

This way you can compare between both Databases without making two connections.

Now if you do not have both in the same place then you can do something like this:

```
mysql_select_db(db1);
$db1Result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db1.tags WHERE id=1");
mysql_select_db(db2);
$db2Result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db2.tags WHERE id=1");
```

And after that compare the results from $db1Result with the ones from $db2Result.

Answer (score 0):

```
//get my conn
include "../../database.php";
//put data in
//get data
if($_GET['attribute']!=''){
    //prepare
    $stmt=$conn->prepare('INSERT INTO databasetablename (attribute) VALUES (?)');
    //bind
    $stmt->bind_param('s',$_GET['attribute']);
    //execute
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
}

    //print data out
    $res=$conn->query("SELECT attribute FROM databasetablename");
    if($res){
        while($hold = mysqli_fetch_array($res,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
            $record[]=$hold;
            echo $hold['attribute'];
        }
    }
    echo '<hr/>';
    //print out
        foreach($record as $cur){
            echo $cur['attribute'].<br/>;
        }
```